# How to improve this email extracting regex?

Tags: python, regex, screen-scraping

I'm using the following regex query to extract emails from website text:

```
email = re.findall(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+',siteresponse.text)
```

The issue I'm facing is it's matching against strings such as:
slick-carousel@1.8.1
CMBT-Web-Logo-white_150x@2x.png

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use a specific pattern to target only email domains at the end.

Comment: This is a very complex issue. The approach I used is matching and skipping those specific patterns that I do not want to match, and only match my email pattern in all other contexts.

Comment: I think the problem here is that your text may contain sequences that *could*, in principle, be email addresses. For example, **2x.png** might be a valid domain name. How could you possibly know other than accepting the response from RE, isolating the domain and then try to resolve that domain name (e.g. ping or some DNS lookup)